# grep: comparing a list of one ore more words in each line with a text file

Tags: list, comparison, grep

I am working on a Debian/GNU Linux OS and like to use a short shell command (terminal or extern script).

My aim: I have a list of words in foo.txt like

---- foo.txt ----

```
dog
cat
mouse with hat
```

---- /foo.txt ----

and want to compare this list with bar.txt (implying normal text with some paragraphs).

*I would like to have two kind of matches:*

1. all words of each line should match (e.g. 'mouse with hat' as well as just 'hat')
2. only the the first appearance of each whole line should match

**Related to the first problem:**

My first code (so far for the command line) and my problems:

```
for i in foo.txt; do fgrep -f foo.txt bar.txt
```

just matches the first word of the list.
Now I think I have to use something like

```
for i in foo.txt; do fgrep -e <some-kind-of-regexp> -f foo.txt bar.txt
```

but I am bogged down with the regexp :(

**Related to the second problem**
For stopping grep I only know the -m option.

```
for i in foo.txt; do fgrep -m 1 -f foo.txt bar.txt
```

stops after the first with any matches. But I like to have something like 'search for any first match and stop after browsing the whole list'.

Answer (score 1):

To your first question, you need to split up the list into its individual words before you give it to grep. I use awk for this, but you could probably use sed too. I am splitting on whitespace, but you could just as easily split on non-alphanumerics if that's what you wanted:

```
fgrep -f <(mawk 'BEGIN{FS=" "}{print; if(NF > 1)for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)print $i}' foo.txt) bar.txt
```

To your second question, you need to get a little fancy. First, output the line number along with each matched string, then you can unique on the matched string to get the line number that matched for each string.

```
cat bar.txt \
| mawk '{print NR,$0}' \
| join -1 1 -2 1 - <(fgrep -o -n -f <(mawk 'BEGIN{FS=" "}{print; if(NF > 1)for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)print $i}' foo.txt) bar.txt \
| sort -k2,2 -k1,1n \
| sort -k2,2 -us \
| cut -f1 \
| sort -k1,1)
```